# Codeigniter - show file name with extension

Tags: php, image, file, codeigniter, extension-methods

I am using `Codeigniter` framework.
i have `codeigniter` view record page.

where im showing file name.
but now i want to show file name and file extension seperately.
like this

```
file name  |  file ext
```

***see my codes below***

*view page*

```
<div class="gallery gallery-2">
<ul class="row">
    <?php $images = $this->fileupload_model->get_all_files(); ?>
    <?php if ($images): ?>
    <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
    <li class="col-md-3 hidden-phone">
        <a class="thumb no-ajaxify" data-gallery="gallery-2" href="#">
        <img style="width:177px;height:130px;" src="/uploads/<?php if ('/uploads/$image->file_url') echo $image->file_url ?><?php else echo "pdf.png" ?>" alt="uploaded files" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        <p>Status: <strong>
        <?php if ($image->status == 2 && 1)
        echo "<a style='text-decoration:underline;' href='/admin/fileupload/status/$image->file_id'>Deactive</a>";
        else
        echo "<a style='text-decoration:underline;' href='/admin/fileupload/status/$image->file_id'>Active</a>";
        ?>
        </strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/admin/fileupload/delete/<?php echo $image->file_id; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></p>
        <p>File Url: <strong><a href="/uploads/<?php echo $image->file_url; ?>" target="_blank">click for url</a></strong></p>
        <div class="separator">&nbsp;</div>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <h2 style="color:red;font-weight:bold;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:17px;">oh Sorry, No Images Found !</h2>
    <?php endif ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

*model*

```
public function files_insert($name_array) //add images from model
{
    foreach ($name_array as $photo)
    {       
        $data = array(
            'file_url' => $photo,
            'status' => '1',
        );

        $this->db->insert('file_upload', $data);
        $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your controller and view code???

Answer (score 1):

Use [getimagesize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

```
$file // path of the file
$result = getimagesize($file);
$mime = $result["mime"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

> The above example will output:
>
> /www/htdocs/inc
>
> inc.php
>
> php
>
> inc

Comment: posting below ..sec please

Comment: wait please..m posting

Comment: where is your controller code???also delete your answer otherwise you get downvote for it??

Comment: then how you render your view??

Comment: public function index()
    {
        $data['mainContent'] = 'admin/uploadfiles/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_template/layout', $data);
    }
this is controller,showing view

Comment: Saty ? are you there ?

Answer (score 0):

[`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) does this magic for you

```
 <?php 
    $ext = pathinfo("file.png", PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    echo $ext ;
    $filename = pathinfo("file.txt", PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $filename;
    ?>
```

This is fast, efficient, reliable and built-in. pathinfo() can give you other information, such as canonical path, depending on the constant you pass to it.

Comment: @NoushadRanani Where you want to show file name and extention seprately

Comment: you want to save filename and extention in database seprately

Comment: i just want to show file name on view record page.which is showing good..put not i want to show extension in second line without file name